# AxWMPlib: How to load playlist from an external file

Tags: vb.net, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am making a media player application using AXWMPlib which has a playlist.
what i successfully able to do was saving the playlist items in a text file.

below is the code for saving:

```
   If SavePlaylist.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim writefile As New System.IO.StreamWriter(SavePlaylist.FileName)
        For i = 0 To lstview.Items.Count - 2
            writefile.WriteLine(Form1.main.AxWMP1.currentPlaylist.Item(i).sourceURL)
        Next
        writefile.Write(Form1.main.AxWMP1.currentPlaylist.Item(Form1.main.AxWMP1.currentPlaylist.count - 1).sourceURL)
        writefile.Close()
    End If
```

for loading i wrote till here:

```
If OpenPlaylist.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Dim readfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(OpenPlaylist.FileName)
            Dim ob As String = readfile.ReadToEnd()
            Dim content() As String = OpenPlaylist.FileName.Split(Environment.NewLine)

        End If
```

i dont know how to read the lines stored in current() and append them in current playlist.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution:

```
If Open.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
                Dim readfile As New System.IO.StreamReader(Open.FileName)
                Dim ob As String = readfile.ReadToEnd()
                Dim content() As String = ob.Split(Environment.NewLine)

                For Each Line As String In content
                    Dim item As IWMPMedia = Form1.AxWMP1.newMedia(Line)
                    Form1.AxWMP1.currentPlaylist.appendItem(item)
                Next

            End If
```